# R install 'png' unable to load shared object

Tags: r, package, png, libpng

When I run install.packages("png"), no matter if I do it within R Studio or as super user from the terminal on my Mac, I receive the following error. I have had no success implementing other solutions for this problem. I am using R 4.0.2 (upgraded from 3.6.3 because that didn't work either). The only solution I have currently is to use my university's virtual desktop R distro, as it works in that. However, it's slow and just not the same.

```
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘png’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/bryce/Library/R/4.0/library/00LOCK-png/00new/png/libs/png.so':
  dlopen(/Users/bryce/Library/R/4.0/library/00LOCK-png/00new/png/libs/png.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libz.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/bryce/Library/R/4.0/library/00LOCK-png/00new/png/libs/png.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Users/bryce/Library/R/4.0/library/png’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘png’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/qd/q49j7g891jn7t368990fflrw0000gn/T/RtmpPhRir5/downloaded_packages’
```

I have tried resolving the problem by reinstalling libpng via homebrew, as well as reinitializing the symlinks, but I've hit a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: Workaround found. Had to purge RStudio and download R before re-downloading RStudio. Seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late to the party here, but **this issue still exists** when trying to install clusterProfiler on M1 Mac.

What fixed it was to install bioconductor and then clusterProfiler in an R session in the terminal and then load the library from Rstudio.